# How to navigate to new page if submission is successful?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form that is submit with some data. I am able to console.log the data and know that form is submitted but I would like to navigate to different page once my form is submitted and submission condition met.

HandleSubmit condition:

```
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
 callback();
} else {
etErrorMessage("Please, submit required data");
setSubmitted(false);
 }
  };

<button onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</button>
```

Comment: If by the other page you mean a view inside the React.js single page, you can use history API for example history.push("/home"). But if the page exist outside of React single page use window.location property or window.open method

Answer (score 2):

If you are using react router, you can use "useNavigate" (https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

If you are not using react router, and you want to change the url, you can use this in your callback.

`window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/test"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react router, you can use the `useHistory` hook and then call `history.push("/some_url")` after your submit. Docs can be found here: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it, I feel so dumb. since I have a sperate custom hook file for handling my form events, I just have to create formSubmit to handle my navigation and pass into my custom hook.